# Get value set from one tpl to another tpl file (smarty template engine) with cscart?

Tags: php, html, smarty, cs-cart

I need to access the value for the variable set with input tag from one tpl file.

This the input tag i have in A.tpl file:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="payment_data[processor_params][enable_addbillcard]" id="optional_enable_addbillcard" value="1" {if $processor_params.enable_addbillcard == "1"}checked="checked"{/if} onclick="{$onchange_method}" />
```

Based from this I do this in B.tpl file:

```
{if $payment_data.processor_params.enable_addbillcard == "1"}
...
{/if}
```

But the if condition does not work when the value is set to 1. The body of the if condition does not show up from the B.tpl file

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out sometime ago now. The tpl file needs to have this at the top:

```
{assign var="payment_data" value=$cart.payment_id|fn_get_payment_method_data}
```

Then one can use further down in the tpl file

```
{if $payment_data.processor_params.enable_addbillcard == "1"}
```

So I think the answer is particular to cscart.

Answer (score 1):

You can access request variables via `$smarty.get...` and/or `$smarty.post...`

Try using

```
{if $smarty.get.payment_data.processor_params.enable_addbillcard == "1"}
```

Or if you use post

```
{if $smarty.post.payment_data.processor_params.enable_addbillcard == "1"}
```

Comment: I tried with $smarty.get... & $smarty.post... Both don't work. The body in if condition does not render. The name of the input field is like an array it seems: payment_data[processor_params][enable_addbillcard]

Comment: How would I get the value from this array in a different tpl file? The input field is in a post action form. Is it not possible to get the value from this input field from another template file?

Comment: @PGup I made a typo. Are form data even sent. Try `print_r(array('get'=>$_GET, 'post'=>$_POST));` before rendering tpl and show me results